# Are smart contracts deployed verified?

Tags: contract-verification

On Ethereum, I understand that one can create a contract and deploy it onto the blockchain. But I am not clear how this contract gets verified by miners before being deployed onto the chain. For example, it can be a voting contract as shown [here](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2) or some other contract for my purpose.

Also, is there any tutorial for programming a miner to verify a specific behaviour, like if there is any infinite loop in the contract deployed.

Comment: It is impossible to check if a program would terminate for sure (halting problem). But since it uses gas when running, it would not be a problem, because it runs out of gas at some time and execution would be stopped

Answer (score 1):

When deploying a contract miners will only execute its constructor. If the constructor finishes correctly the contract will be added to the Ethereum's world state.

There's no other verification Miners only execute a sequence of EVM opcodes, they make no verification if the sequence of opcodes was matches a source code.

Some block explorer provide "verified" sources that matches the deployed opcodes. But that is an extra service and you have to trust the reputation of the block explorer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please provide a reference for this information? Any idea about how we can code miner program?

Comment: The cannonical formal reference is [Ethereum's Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), but it is too technical.   There's a nice article that deals with the [Contract creation process](https://medium.com/@hayeah/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-part-5-the-smart-contract-creation-process-cb7b6133b855). If you only want to implement a miner perhaps taking a look a the implementation of [cpp-ethereum miners](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/tree/develop/libethashseal) is a better place.

Answer (score 0):

When smart contract is deployed, its byte code is executed starting from the beginning.  This actually executes the constructor of the smart contract, and at the end of execution constructor usually loads into memory byte code of the rest of smart contract, i.e. byte code of the smart contract with constructor code stripped form the beginning, and returns offset and length of the loaded byte code.

This constructor execution may be treated as "verification" of byte code because EVM will revert the transaction in case byte code will try to do something illegal, e.g. execute opcode that EVM does not know, or jump to an instruction other than JUMPDEST, etc.  Though only constructor code is "verified" at this stage.

When deployed smart contract is called by a transaction, EVM executed its byte code, as it was returned by constructor, and this execution may also be treaded as "verification".  Though, only the parts of byte code laying across execution path are "verified".

In other words, miner "verifies" only those parts of byte code that he executes, and only when he executes them.  The whole smart contract is never verified.  Moreover, there could be unreachable parts of byte code, and that part will never be verified.